# JQuery event dosen't work after .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the div#1 dosen't change text. What i'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="1" class="a" style="width: 300px;height: 300px; background-color: #003366"></div>
<div id="2" class="b" style="width: 300px;height: 300px; background-color: #003366"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").click(function(){
       $(this).text("hello");
    });

    $(".a").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).addClass("b");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: delegate event so selector of targeted element is evaluated 'on the fly'

Comment: `id` shouldn't start with number

Comment: Before someone said the opposite, @UnknownUser is correct when saying `shouldn't`

Comment: shouldn't, but it can in HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("body")
.on('click', '.a', function (){
   $(this).addClass("b");
})
.on('click', '.b', function (){
    $(this).text("hello");
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Event handlers are added to the elements that match the selector **at that time**, changing the selector later does not magically make the event handler work.

You could use delegated event handlers for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".b", function(){
       $(this).text("hello");
    });

    $(".a").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).addClass("b");
    });
});
```

But why are you doing this, it seems like a strange pattern to activate a click handler only after the same element has been hovered, as you couldn't possibly click it unless the mouse is over it ?

Comment: I actually want to understand events handlers.This was the easy way to explain my doubt. thank you

Comment: @rayashi - You're welcome, and you should really read up on events as well, since you've accepted an answer (and unaccepted this answer) that doesn't even use the mouseover event, but a click event instead ?